# Better way to process huge files

Tags: algorithms, python, file-handling, buffers

I have a huge csv file and I have to process that file and do some data manipulation. Right now I'm reading/loading the file in buffer and then doing the data processing work. I find this approach inefficient incase the file is very large. Would it be better to load/read chunk of file then process it and keep doing it until the file is completely processed? I need suggestions.

Comment: In general, reading a file completely, doing all processing in memory, and writing the result in one chunk should be most efficient if you have sufficient RAM so the OS does not need to swap. So what is the reason you think it may be inefficient? Do you have actual data showing a performance degradation above some file size? Or is it just a feeling that processing a million-line file takes much longer than a thousand-line file?

Comment: What to do depends on many factors: on the meaning "huge" or "large" in your case, what kind of "processing", what "data manipulation", and on the gory details of which data structure you used for the buffer and how the current data processing takes place. We don't have a crystal ball telling us these points, so in the current form, don't be astonished if your question gets closed soon.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still thinking about the scope of a single computer, you can scale up with threading, and a producer/consumer pattern or similar. Basically have one thread that just reads the file, puts the lines into a queue, and have N threads that pick elements out of the queue and process them. This way you'll be IO and/or CPU bounded. You can limit memory usage if you put a limit on the queue size, i.e. when the queue is huge, the producer side waits a little and then continues.

To scale up, you should change the process that generates the huge input file to instead produce many smaller files, called sharding. You can look at dataflow frameworks like Beam to help you distribute the processing among many computers.